# Reading Binary Files with different byte length value inside

Tags: c, c++11, io

How to read a binary file with different format of length?

for example there are  a specific value after 3200 bytes of binary file which formated in 4 bytes, 2 bytes, 2 bytes, and 1 bytes.

I tried to read using

```
fread(&buffer, 1, 1, file);
```

then contenate the 4 bytes char in buffer variable - into one char - then convert it to integer but it doesn't work. Only show like if it was one byte length.

Comment: because of endianness?

Comment: no, it's in Big Endian.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  Provide code and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you seek to the position you want to read:

```
fseek(file, 3200, SEEK_SET);
```

Then read the 4 bytes out of the file to the integer you want:

```
int n;
fread(&n, 4, 1, file);
```

This works if the endian of the file and your system are the same. Otherwise you convert the number to the endian of you system. E.g.

```
// if the file is big endian:
m = be32toh(n);
// if the file is little endian:
m = le32toh(n);
```